# Java Method to Check if URL Fits Pattern

Tags: java, string-matching

I have the need to do some primitive url matching in java.  I need a method that will return true, saying

```
/users/5/roles
```

matches

```
/users/*/roles
```

Here is what I am looking for and what I tried.

```
public Boolean fitsTemplate(String path, String template) {
    Boolean matches = false;
    //My broken code, since it returns false and I need true
    matches = path.matches(template);
    return matches;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you may want an Ant matcher; there are libraries available for this.

Comment: What should be returned for `users/5/6/7/roles`? [String.matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) takes a regular expression, `/users/[0-9]+/roles` should work.

Comment: @JohnBupit You are right, .matches() does take a regex, and the regex you supplied works.  Unfortunately, I'm trying to write code to accommodate the existing arguments.  For the purposes of this question, assume the provided arguments are all you have to work with.

Comment: Not related to your question, but… you should be using primitive `boolean`, not java.lang.Boolean.  The latter forces callers of your method to check for a null return value.

Comment: @VGR that would be the case if I didn't always initialize the returned Boolean object with a boolean value.  It is impossible for callers of the method to receive a null Boolean object.

Comment: Then why not make the return type `boolean`, so callers don’t need to read your source code to verify that?

Comment: @VGR that makes sense.  I suppose I always try to write methods that return non-null objects and call them with that presumption.  But a presumption still exists and returning boolean could eliminate that presumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to replace the `*` with some kind of regex equivalent such as `[^/]+`, but the kind of pattern being used here is actually called a "glob" pattern. Starting in Java 7, you can use [`FileSystem.getPathMatcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)) to match file paths against glob patterns. For a complete explanation of the glob syntax, see the documentation for `getPathMatcher`.

```
public boolean fitsTemplate(String path, String template) {
    return FileSystems.getDefault()
                      .getPathMatcher("glob:" + template)
                      .matches(Paths.get(path));
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is perfect.  I remember the term "glob" in reference to url/path matching from my exposure to Javascript task runners like Gulp.  It uses globs all the time to communicate a pattern to match.